# An error occured during the beamer in order to create presentation

Tags: beamer, texstudio

I ran the following code in order to create a simple presentation.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
    %\author{}
    %\title{}
    %\subtitle{}
    %\logo{}
    %\institute{}
    %\date{}
    %\subject{}
    %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
    %\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But, I got the following error.

```
Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/AA/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_TW8220".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

I clicked the `C:/Users/AA/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log`
and it includes the following writings. 
    2018-04-23 17:47:29,008+0300 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from beamer.tar.lzma...
    2018-04-23 17:47:32,549+0300 FATAL pdflatex - The installed file does not exist.
    2018-04-23 17:47:32,549+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\translator\translator.sty"
    2018-04-23 17:47:32,549+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
    2018-04-23 17:47:32,549+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 55
    2018-04-23 17:47:32,550+0300 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1

**How can I solve the problem?**

Comment: Did you save your document with a name of your choice before compilation?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371460/cant-use-beamer-package-on-windows-because-translator-sty-is-missing/422169#422169 might help

Comment: No. I will firstly use the beamer for a presentation. Could you help me pls.

Comment: No to what?~~~~

Comment: I didn't save my document with a name before compilation.

Comment: oK, use "save as" to save it in a location and with a name of your choice. Then compile again.

Comment: I did now. But I got same error

Comment: Does the line "`Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_TW8220".tex"`" now contain your actual filename?
`

Comment: Now, I have 2018-04-23 18:17:04,942+0300 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from beamer.tar.lzma...
2018-04-23 18:17:08,685+0300 FATAL pdflatex - The installed file does not exist.
2018-04-23 18:17:08,685+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\translator\translator.sty"
2018-04-23 18:17:08,685+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2018-04-23 18:17:08,685+0300 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 55
2018-04-23 18:17:08,686+0300 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1

Comment: Install the `translator` package via the Miktex console

Comment: @1_student Great! First problem solved. Now try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372819/36296

Comment: @1_student Good to hear your problem is solved!

Comment: @1_student A few comments about your code: you don't need `\usetheme{default}`, this is loaded as default

Comment: @1_student In most cases it is better to move `%\author{}
    %\title{}
    %\subtitle{}
    %\logo{}
    %\institute{}
    %\date{}
    %\subject{}` before `\begin{document}` because it is then also included in the pdf meta data